# execute function once inside animation loop at certain time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to visualize some audio and need to execute a function at certain time once. The animation loop should be syncronized with player and when player current time reaches 10s, a function is executed. The timeupdate event fires depending on browser and time variable never equals  10.  What is the most efficient way to achieve that ?

```
var time =0;

var player = document.getElementById('player');

player.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(e){

    time = e.target.currentTime;

},false);


var doOnce = function(){

    console.log('do something once');

};


function loop(){

    //update and draw animation

    //execute doOnce when player.currentTime >= 10
    if( doOnce && time >= 10 ){

        //is this bad practice?
        doOnce = doOnce();

    }
    setTimeout(loop,32);
}

loop();
player.play();
```

Comment: Can you explain more? When do you want this function to be run once?

Comment: If you want to invoke `doOnce` only once then what's the point of `loop`. Just a single `setTimeout(doOnce, 32)` would suffice.

Comment: @Redu Updated question. The loop updates and draws animation. I want doOnce to be executed when player reches 10s.

Comment: @clabe45 When player.currentTime reaches 10s.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little “functional programming magic” to achieve this in an elegant way:

```
var time = 0;

var player = document.getElementById('player');

player.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(e){
    time = e.target.currentTime;
},false);

function callback(){
    console.log('do something once');
}

function doOnceAfterElapsedTime(func, elapsedTime) {
    var done = false;
    return function () {
        if (done || elapsedTime < time) {
            return;
        }
        func();
        done = true;
    }
}

const callbackThatExecutesOnceAfterElapsedTime = doOnceAfterElapsedTime(callback, 10);

function loop(){
    callbackThatExecutesOnceAfterElapsedTime();
    setTimeout(loop,32);
}

loop();
player.play();
```

The function `doOnceAfterElapsedTime` creates a new function that makes sure that the wrapped `callback` function is only executed once, after the specified time has elapsed.

Comment: In that way the function call is made every time the loop runs. Not very efficient ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var execute = false;

vid.ontimeupdate = function() {

 if(vid.currentTime >= 5 && !execute){
  myFunction();
  execute = true;
 }
 
};

function myFunction() {
  console.log('executed')
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += 'executed';
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<div id='res'></div>
```

You can check for specific audio/video time using `obj.currentTime` and call function after that much of time elapsed.

Comment: You are right, it´s better to move function execution from loop to timeupdate event cause it fires less often, still, it could be messy to create executed flag for every function, if there are a lot of them. That´s why i doOnce = doOnce()

Answer (score 0):

`timeUpdate` event might be very busy. Especially as you say you have many of these, you will  probably end up filling up the event queue with tons of useless time checking tasks. This might delay the execution of some other callbacks those fired by other events. Why don't you just set up another similar loop to dirty check time from `player.currentTime` element but this time like `setTimeout(loop2, 500)`. Trigger this second loop like

```
player.removeEventListener("playing", loop2, false) // in case paused and restarted
player.addEventListener("playing", loop2, false)
```